# what is the reason of having this in the category Alternative Store View Localizations

Tags: magento2, categories

Need to understand the use and need of Alternative Store View Localizations under the categories.

Im trying to understand the need of it, it says alternate name of the category or something else need to give. When we create a category at one store can we use it another store by adding its name under this section.